# How do I best store and call upon a pandas script that operates on a single XLSX file?

Tags: python, pandas, class, object, methods

I have a Python script that makes use of Pandas to read in an excel `XLSX` file to a `DateFrame`, perform some calculations & grouping, and generate a new `DataFrame` with the information I desire. All is fine and dandy there.

I want to now put this into production and call this script from a larger class that manages a series of operations I want to do with the info (put it into PDF, e-mail it, etc...) - **how do I best 'store' and call this script?**

Do I create a separate `.py` file and just place this script in a function that returns a `DataFrame`?  Or do I make a `Class` that initializes and contains the `DataFrame` and can be called upon?

I realize it's a bit of a broad question, but I just want to understand what best practice may be, or just what most people like to do.

**EDIT:** To make my question more specific and less subjective - are these acceptable ways of storing and calling a pandas script?

Comment: how will the script know what the file is? (genuinely interested)

Comment: i would pass it in as a parameter from the calling class - that class would have it's own method to determine the file needed `df = pd.read_excel(passed_param)`

Comment: I think this question is too much opinion based. Both ways seems good to me, the "best" one is a matter of taste.

Comment: i edited the question to make it less subjective